# C# TypeConverter suppresses (milli)seconds when converting DateTime

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, type-conversion, typeconverter

I use a `TypeConverter` to convert `DateTime` instances to and from strings.

When using the culture dependent functions `ConvertTo/FromString` it seems that the seconds and milliseconds parts of the `DateTime` don't get converted.

When using the culture invariant functions `ConvertTo/FromInvariantString` the milliseconds are still missing. Either way the two `DateTime` instances before and after the conversion are never equal, as I would have expected.

This class demonstrates the effect:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class DateToStringConversionTest 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime));
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime( 2010, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );

        // convert to / from invariant string
        string   s3 = tc.ConvertToInvariantString(d1);
        DateTime d3 = (DateTime) tc.ConvertFromInvariantString(s3);
        Console.WriteLine( "invariant string\n   {0}\n=> {1}\n=> {2}\n=> equals? {3}", 
              d1, s3, d3, d1.Equals(d3) );

        // convert to / from string
        string   s2 = tc.ConvertToString(d1);
        DateTime d2 = (DateTime) tc.ConvertFromString(s2);
        Console.WriteLine( "\nstring\n   {0}\n=> {1}\n=> {2}\n=> equals? {3}", 
              d1, s2, d2, d1.Equals(d2) );
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
string
02.01.2010 03:04:05 => 02.01.2010 03:04 => 02.01.2010 03:04:00 => equals? False
invariant string
02.01.2010 03:04:05 => 01/02/2010 03:04:05 => 02.01.2010 03:04:05 => equals? False
```

I'm running on the German locale, so the dates are output as `DD.MM.YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `DateTime.Parse/TryParse` and `DateTime.ToString()` which doesn't cut of milliseconds. I don't see the reason why this wouldn't work for you either.

Comment: Same problem here: d1.Equals( DateTime.Parse( d1.ToString() ) ) returns False